# Cannot Access $errors in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am having a issue with Laravel 5.2 accessing the $errors variable in my partial.

**routes.php**

[image]

I have wrapped my routes in the middleware web.

**and in my auth.blade.php**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="panel panel-{{ $errors->all() ? 'danger' : 'default'}}">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                       `enter code here`<h2 class="panel-title">@yield('heading')</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            @if($errors->all())
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <strong>We found some errors</strong>
                                    <ul>
                                        @foreach($errors->all() as $errors)
                                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            @endif
                            @yield('content')
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**here is the code for my login partial**

```
@extends('layouts.auth')

@section('title','Login')

@section('heading','Welcome Please login')

@section('content')
    {!! Form::open() !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('email') !!}
        {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('password') !!}
        {!! Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    {!! Form::submit('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}

    <a href="#" class="small">Forgot password?</a>

    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

when i click login it just redirects to the same page buit not flashing the errors?

When i click login it shows this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVFKu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `web` middleware, this may cause empty `$errors`. Since 5.2.27, `web` middleware aplies automatically to all routes and you shouldn't add it again manually.

Comment: Hi Alexey, when i remove the group i still get the same issue where when i post the form it redirects back to same page and doesnt show errors?

Comment: Are you sure you have any errors when you're trying to dislay them? I mean maybe everything is ok and that's why you don't have any error messages? ) Also, I think its better to use more explicit `@if (count($errors) > 0)` instead of `@if($errors->all())`.

Comment: I made the if more implicit and this isnt working either , i changed the kernel.php as i moved  \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, AND
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,

out of the $middlewaregroupes into the middleware , now i changed it back to how it was origianlly i get this error

Undefined variable: error 
Undefined variable: error (View: /home/vagrant/Code/hub/public/themes/default/views/layouts/auth.blade.php) (View: /home/vagrant/Code/hub/public/themes/default/views/layouts/auth.blade.php)

Comment: i have attached a screenshot of the error @AlexeyMezenin

Comment: Error message says you're using `$error` instead of `$errors` somewhere.

Comment: bingo got it! thank you so much for your help! i cannot thank you enough!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. )